# Android SharedPreferences not working as expected

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'd like to save some usersettings in SharedPreferences, but somehow, the saved string is always empty, when i'm reading it back.

Saving..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("AAAAPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edits = prefs.edit();
                    edits.putString("request_id", requestId);
                    edits.putInt("active", active);
                    edits.commit();
```

Reading..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("AAAAPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String request_id = prefs.getString("request_id", "");
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank's for your help!

EDIT:

```
new HttpHandler() {
                @Override
                public HttpUriRequest getHttpRequestMethod() {
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("***********");
                    try {
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", textName.getText().toString()));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return httppost;
                }
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String result) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONObject response = obj.getJSONObject("response");
                        String requestId = response.getString("request_id");
                        int active = response.getInt("active");

                        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("AAAAPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edits = prefs.edit();
                        edits.putString("request_id", requestId);
                        edits.putInt("active", active);
                        edits.commit();

                        /* MORE... */

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        // Error.
                    }
                }
            }.execute();
```

Comment: Does it throw any kind of exception or is it just an empty string?

Comment: Sadly i'm not getting any exceptions or anything.. Just an empty string.

Comment: are You sure that requestId is not empty? This code above seems like it should work. Could You show a little bit more of Your code, where exactly You are setting and getting the prefs?

Comment: I debugged through it and requestId is not empty as I set it. I'm setting it in a del. after a HTTP Request. Will update the answer with more code. Thank's for your help!

Comment: When are you trying to read the value?

Comment: In another activity, where the read value is @"".. I really have no idea why.

Comment: wild guess.. an exception is thrown during the json's parsing, and you are never setting the string.

Comment: Already checked that.. it runs through everything and then opens the next activity.. I also checked if the SharedPreferences is not null.. Is there any way to check if the writing was successful?

Comment: * commit returns a boolean.. will check that out.. EDIT: returns true.. mhm.. I really hate this kind of problems ^^

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work when I instantiate the SharedPreferences with the following code:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static void saveOrEdit(Context context ,String name,
            String key , String value,Class clz){
        if(null == context || StringUtil.isEmpty(name)){
            return;
        }
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if(null != clz){
            if(clz.getSimpleName().equals("Boolean")){
                editor.putBoolean(key, Boolean.valueOf(value));
            }else if(clz.getSimpleName().equals("Float")){
                editor.putFloat(key, Float.valueOf(value));
            }else if(clz.getSimpleName().equals("Integer")){
                editor.putInt(key, Integer.valueOf(value));
            }else if(clz.getSimpleName().equals("Long")){
                editor.putLong(key, Long.valueOf(value));
            }else{
                editor.putString(key, value);
            }
        }else{          
            editor.putString(key, value);
        }
        //It should be submitted
        editor.commit();
    }
```